# Why are $-1,1$ the only diagonalizable eigenvalues for orthogonal operators?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, diagonalization, orthogonal-matrices

I've known that for an $f$ orthogonal operator to be diagonalizable, the eigenvalues have to be real, but what doesn't make sense to me, is that they have to be $-1$ or $1$ in order to be diagonalizable. I've learnt that those eigenvalues correspond to rotations and reflections, but why $-1$ and $1$? What makes them special? My thoughts are that since it is called "orthogonal" their bases have to be orthogonal, and by doing a rotation or a reflection, their base remain to be orthogonal after the transformation. What is it?

Comment: An orthogonal operator, by definition, preserves the inner product. If $v$ is an eigenvector, we necessarily have $\Vert f(v)\Vert=\Vert v\Vert$. Which eigenvalues are possible for this equation to hold?

Comment: @Levent is there a more geometrical way to visualise this?

Comment: @Levent I've reasked my thoughts on a new, and better written question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4689455/visualising-geometrically-lambda-pm-1-eigenvalues-for-orthogonal-transformat