# Visualising geometrically $\lambda=\pm 1$ eigenvalues for orthogonal transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, diagonalization, orthogonal-matrices

The sole purpose of this post is to gather **geometrical intuition** behind *why are the eigenvalues of an orthogonal matrix which is diagonalisable over the reals
equal to ±1*. Now I know they both represent rotations or reflections, but what makes $\lambda=\pm 1$ special to make the transformation orthogonal and yet diagonalisable? What am I looking to distinguish if those are the eigenvalues that make it to be *diagonalisable*?

I imagine a proper subspace in $\mathbb{R}^2$, like a line $V_1$, and it's eigenvector that gets mapped to itself ($\lambda=1$) or to it's opposite ($\lambda=-1$) but  I don't know how that makes it diagonalisable, nor I don't see any "rotation" there. Anyone can shine a light on all this with some geometrical inputs?

Comment: The (complex) eigenvalues of an orthogonal matrix must have norm $1$, i.e., must lie on the unit circle $S^1\subset \mathbb{C}$. But if the matrix is further diagonalizible over the reals, then its eigenvalues are also real. The result follows from the observation that $S^1\cap \mathbb{R}=\{-1,1\}$. I am not sure how geometric this explanation is.

Comment: @Levent appreciate it once again but it isn't giving me geometric intuition about it. Like why are -1 and 1 the only diagonalisable eigenvalues? I've seen the algebraic demostration, but I'd rather see some geometric approach to it

Comment: @Aley20 Your question is unclear. What is the meaning of a 'diagonalisable eigenvalue' ?

Comment: @Digitallis an eigenvalue that makes the orthogonal transformation to be diagonalisable, my bad if it wasn't clear, must've been a language mistake

Comment: Can your question be rephrased as " Why are the eigenvalues of an orthogonal matrix which is diagonalisable over $\mathbb R$ equal to $ \pm 1$"

Comment: @Digitallis sure.. but can you help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is a good, but perhaps a loaded, dense question. I want to address certain points just to clarify some possible misconceptions based on your question before I try to adequately answer.

**Possible Misconception 1)** Let's look at this statement of yours,

> ... what makes $\lambda = \pm 1$ special to make the transformation orthogonal and yet diagonalizable.

A given matrix having eigenvalues $\pm 1$ does not imply it is orthogonal or even diagonalizable. Consider the matrix $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$. This matrix only has eigenvalue $1$ but cannot be diagonalized and is certainly not orthogonal.

**Possible Misconception 2)** This also relates to your other example.

> Imagine a proper subspace in $\mathbb{R}^2$, like a line $V_1$, and its eigenvector that gets mapped to itself, ... but I don't know how that makes it diagonalizable.

The same matrix that I mentioned before, $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$, has a single eigenvector corresponding to eigenvalue $1$, but is not diagonalizable.

**Possible Misconception 3)**

Looking at the comment on the post there is this exchange.

> Like why are -1 and 1 the only diagonalisable eigenvalues?

If a a given matrix, $A$, is orthogonal (i.e satisfies $A^TA = I$), then **it can** have eigenvalues not equal to $\pm 1$. Consider the following matrix which is simply rotates the plane by 90 degrees counter clockwise,
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}
$$

If you solve for the eigenvalues you will get $i$ and $-i$. So it is important to realize sometimes you may have eigevalues $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$. That is your eigenvalues may be imaginary numbers. Your question was edited to say *diagonalizable over the reals* however if this was something you were not aware of I think it is conceptually important to the story.

**Possible Misconception 4)**

You seem to be thinking the specific eigenvalues are what make it diagonalizable. They do not! The fact that an orthogonal matrix, $A$, satisfies $A^TA=I$ is what makes it diagonalizable. There are two primary points about orthogonal matrices.

1. If a matrix is orthogonal, then it is diagonalizable
2. If a matrix is orthogonal, then it has eigenvalues with magnitude $1$.

So it is not about the fact that orthogonal matrices sometimes have eigenvalues $\pm 1$ that make them diagonalizable. There are plenty of matrices with eigenvalues $\pm 1$ that are not diagonalizable. The fact that orthogonal matrices are diagonalizable stems from the fact they satisfy this nontrivial equation, $A^TA=I$.

Following this we are left with several points related to your question which I think need to be addressed.

### 1) What does it mean to be diagonalizable?

A matrix, $A$, is diagonalizable **if** there exists $n$ linearly independent non-zero vectors that get mapped to a scalar multiple of themselves. That is $n$ linearly independent vectors, $v_i$ satisfy $ Av_i = \lambda_i v_i$. Intuitively stretch the axes.

Important disclaimer is that many times we allow the $\lambda_i$ to be complex so it doesn't look like stretching the axes in $\mathbb{R}$, it looks like stretching them in $\mathbb{C}$.

### 2) When is a matrix diagonalizable?

A matrix, $A$, is diagonalizable **when** there exists $n$ linearly independent non-zero vectors. How do we know if there $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors? This question is somewhat hard!

For any matrix you can compute the eigenvalues and see what all the possible eigenvectors are. If there are not enough then the matrix is not diagonalizable.

For example, for the matrix I refer to in Misconception 1), you show it is not diagonalizable by trying to find enough eigenvectors and consequently realizing it is impossible to have enough because the dimension of the null space of $A-I$ is 1 in that particular example.

However there are important special cases where it is easy to tell if a matrix is diagonalizable!

1. The $n$-by-$n$ matrix, $A$ has $n$ distinct eigenvalues. That is it has $n$ eigenvalues that are all different from each other
2. When a given $n$-by-$n$ matrix of real values satisfies $A^TA = AA^T$
3. When a given $n$-by-$n$ matrix of real values is symmetric that is $A=A^T$.

### 3) Why are orthogonal matrices always diagonalizable?

An orthogonal matrix, $A$, satisfies $A^TA = AA^T = I$. That is the inverse of $A$ is its transpose. Thus the fact it is diagonalizable follows from the second special case listed in the previous section.

Your question seems to indicate this is the place where you are really looking for intuition geometrically. Why does obeying this strange condition $A^TA = AA^T = I$ give us that $A$, is diagonalizable? I will first remark that rigorously this fact follows from the spectral theorem for normal operators. So for full mathematical details you can look at a proof of the spectral theorem for normal operators.

To have some geometric intuition about why $A^TA = AA^T = I$ tells us $A$, is diagonalizable we need some intuition about what $A^T$ is geometrically. Building intuition should come from examples so look at the following few. For all of the following example compute and describe what $\mathbf{B} = \mathbf{A}^T$ does? You should find that in some sense it "undoes the rotations, but does the same stretching on different axes".

#### Example 1)

We consider the matrix which rotates vectors by $\theta = \frac{\pi}{4}$. Explicity we know that we can write this matrix as,
$$
    \mathbf{A} = \begin{bmatrix}
                     \cos(\theta) & -\sin(\theta) \\\\
                     \sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta) 
                \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
                     \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}  \\\\
                     \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}  & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} 
                \end{bmatrix}
$$

[image: Pictures of example 1]

#### Example 2)

We consider the matrix which rotates vectors by $\theta = \frac{\pi}{4}$ and scales uniformly by a factor of $2$. Explicity we know that we can write this matrix as,

$$ 
\mathbf{A} = \begin{bmatrix}
                     2 & 0\\\\
                     0 & 2 
                \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
                     \cos(\theta) & -\sin(\theta) \\\\
                     \sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta) 
                \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
                     2 & 0\\\\
                     0 & 2 
                \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
                     \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}  \\\\
                     \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}  & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} 
                \end{bmatrix}
$$
[image: Image of example 2]

#### Example 3)

We consider the matrix which scales the $x$-axis by $2$ and $y$-axis by $0$ and  rotates vectors by $\theta = \frac{\pi}{4}$. Explicitly we know that we can write this matrix as,

$$
    \mathbf{A} =  \begin{bmatrix}
                     \cos(\theta) & -\sin(\theta) \\\\
                     \sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta) 
                \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
                     2 & 0\\\\
                     0 & 0 
                \end{bmatrix} =  \begin{bmatrix}
                     \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}  \\\\
                     \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}  & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} 
                \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
                     2 & 0\\\\
                     0 & 0 
                \end{bmatrix}
$$
[image: Image of example 3]

Now if you think about what $A^TA = AA^T = I$ some intuition could be that that since $A^T$ "undoes the rotations of $A$ but does the stretching again", that there is in fact "no stretching or squishing". That is the eigenvalues should have magnitude $1$. Therefore in some intuitive sense $A$ is only "rotating things" and we then know it commutes with $A^T$ which "rotates backwards". This notion vaguely places some constraints on how axes should move but says that since going forward and back look similar it looks like a rotation which should be diagonalizable using complex numbers.(Look at examples where they don't commute like the matrix in misconception 1) Some rigor or intuition can be brought to these ideas with something called the polar decomposition. Overall this was very hand wavy, but hopefully helps give some vague inkling why this might be true. I highly highly recommend drawing and playing around with more example on paper by yourself. It is essential.

### 4) Why do the eigenvalues of orthogonal matrices have complex magnitude 1.

Suppose $A$ is an orthogonal matrix and $Av = \lambda v$. We compute $(Av)^*Av = v^*A^TAv = v^*v = |\lambda|^2v^*v \implies |\lambda|^2 = 1$. The symbol $v^*$ means take $v^T$ except with the complex conjugate of all the values, referred to as the conjugate transpose. This guarantees $v^*v \neq 0$. See that $v^Tv = 0$ for eigenvectors of the 90 degree counter clockwise turn.

### 5) When might the eigenvalues be real and not complex?

It turns out in the third special case listed in section 2 we have a guarantee that the eigenvalues are real. That is a matrix is symmetric its eigenvalues are real.

Answer (score 2):

The thing that makes orthogonal matrices special is that they dont "stretch" or "squish" space. Consider an orthgonal matrix $ A$, and a general vectors $ u, v$, **not necessarily** eigenvectors of $ A$.

Recall that orthogonal matrices have the property
$$ u\cdot v=( Au)\cdot ( Av)$$
This property of not stretching or squishing space means that,
$$| A v|=\sqrt{( A v)\cdot ( A v)}=\sqrt{ v\cdot  v}=| v|$$

So orthogonal matrices are "magnitude preserving", that is $Av$ can be no larger or smaller than $v$. Therefore the requirement that the magnitude of an eigenvalue be $1$ is obvious, because i.e
$$Av=\lambda v \\ |Av|=|\lambda v| \\ |v|=|\lambda ||v| \\ |\lambda |=1 \\ \implies \lambda=\pm 1$$

Comment: I really appreciate it but I'm looking for a *geometric* approach as I wrote in bold in my post, on any case, thanks but it isn't what I'm looking for specifically.

Comment: @Aley20 This **is** a geometric approach. If that is not apparent, then you're not really clear about what "geometric" means to you...

Comment: @V.S.e.H. I was expecting some pictures/drawings to be fair at the very least, to call it geometric.

Comment: @Aley20 What isn't "geometric" about it? E.g in two dimensions, a vector that is on the unit sphere will remain on the unit sphere under any orthogonal transformation. I can see an extremely clear picture of this in my head - no need to draw it.

Answer (score 1):

I feel as though there are multiple questions here.

Eigenvalues of an orthogonal matrix over $\mathbb{R}$ have to be $\pm 1$:

Orthogonal matrices preserve angles and lengths (as defined by the standard inner product) and if $v$ is an eigenvector of an orthogonal matrix $A$, then $Av$ is a multiple of $v$ and has the same length as $v$. You have a $1$ dimensional subspace spanned by $v$ and $Av$ should be in the (zero dimensional) sphere in this space (which has a norm given by the inner product). That leaves $Av = \pm v$. This is the content of the other answer and the comments. Over the complex numbers, the span of $v$ is "two dimensional" and the sphere is a circle.

If you think of orthogonal matrices as rotations, the eigenspace for eigenvalue $1$ is an axis of rotation (this only makes sense in $3$-dimensions, in higher dimensions you can have multiple "axes of rotations"). Also, note that in three dimensions there is always an eigenvalue because an odd degree polynomial (the characteristic polynomial) over the reals has at least one real root, so there is always an axis of rotation (up to a sign).

In two dimensions, having an eigenvector of $1$ means you have an axis of rotation and the matrix is the identity transform or a reflection (think about why this is so in terms of orthogonal complement of the eigenspace and the defining property of orthogonal matrices). Similarly, in three dimensions, having two independent eigenvectors forces a third in the orthogonal complement of the first two.

---

Are all orthogonal matrices diagonalizable? No, rotation by $\pi/2$, for example, has no (real) eigenvalues. However, over the complex numbers, the spectral theorem gives a diagonalization (with complex entries, of course).

Is every matrix with $\pm 1$ eigenvalues orthogonal? No, $\begin{bmatrix} 1&1\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$ has eigenvalue $1$ but is not orthogonal or diagonalizable. Of course, if there are $n$ independent eigenvectors, then my matrix is diagonalizable and if a matrix is diagonal and orthogonal, then it must have $\pm 1$s on the diagonal.

Comment: for a rotation to be diagonalisable (let's take an example in 2 dimensions first and the eigenspace to be a line in $\mathbb{R}^2$), it must be a $0^\circ$ or a $180^\circ$ rotation, right? Since otherwise it doesn't stay on the same line, or am I thinking this wrongly?

Comment: @Aley20 Yes, in two dimensions. (Note that by "line" I didn't mean the coordinate axes, the eigenvectors, in general, could point in any direction.) You can take it as an exercise to figure out the matrix for rotation by $\theta$ in two dimensions, verify it's orthogonal and compute its eigenvalues.

Answer (score 1):

Let $e_1,...,e_n$ denote the canonical basis of $\mathbb R^n$ and let $v\in \mathbb R^n$.

Recall that the length of a vector $v = (v_1,...,v_n) = v_1e_1 + ... + v_ne_n$ is by definition equal to the quantity
$$ \sqrt{\sum_i v_i^2}$$
Indeed this is just Pythagoras' theorem ! This is obvious when working in dimension 2 as it is obvious to see that in order to  compute the length of a vector like $v = (1,3)$ you would draw a right triangle using the vectors $e_1, 3e_2$ and $e_1 + 3e_2$ and apply Pythagoras to  said triangle.

Let $T : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$  be a linear transformation and apply this transformation to the above triangle. This yields a new triangle defined by $T(e_1)$,$3T(e_2)$ and $T(v) = T(e_1) + 3T(e_2)$

It is not guarantied that this new triangle is a right-triangle so we cannot use pythagoras' in the same straightforward manor to determine the length of $T(v)$. However, if $T$ was such that $T(e_1)$ and $T(e_2)$ were perpendicular then we could. Moreover if $T(e_1)$ and $T(e_2)$ both had length equal to $1$ then it would be clear that $v$ and $T(v)$ would necessarily have the same length. That is, $\Vert T(v) \Vert = \Vert v \Vert$

In higher dimensions we have the following result

> Let $T : \mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R^n$ be a linear transformation such that  $T(e_1),....,T(e_n)$ forms an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb R^n$, then
> $$ \Vert T(v) \Vert  = \Vert v \Vert$$ for all $v \in \mathbb R^n.$
> In particular the real eigenvalues of $T$ are either $1$ or $-1$.

Finally recall that a matrix $T$ is called orthogonal if and only if $T^tT = I$. This last condition is the same as saying that the column vectors $T(e_1),...,T(e_n)$ of $T$ form an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb R^n$. Indeed this is because the $ij$ entry of the matrix $T^tT$ is exactly the dot product of $T(e_i)$ and $T(e_j)$

---

Note that I have not included any drawings but I'm sure you are capable of drawing two triangles to satisfy your geometric cravings.

Answer (score 1):

Let consider the simple reflection in the plane with respect to $x$ axis such that

- $e_1=(1,0) \to e_1=(1,0)$
- $e_2=(0,1) \to -e_2=(0,-1)$

which in matrix form can be represented by

$$A_0=\begin{bmatrix} 1&0\\0&-1\end{bmatrix}\implies A_0 \begin{bmatrix} a\\b\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} a\\-b\end{bmatrix}$$

Clearly, by definition, the given transformation has eigenvalues $\pm 1$ with eigenvectors $e_1$, $e_2$.

More in general, any other reflection with respect to a line (passing through the origin) forming a counterclockwise angle $\theta$ with $x$ axis can be obtained by

- $u_1=(\cos \theta,\sin \theta) \to u_1=(\cos \theta,\sin \theta)$
- $u_2=(-\sin \theta,\cos \theta) \to -u_2=(\sin \theta,-\cos \theta)$

which in matrix form can be represented by (note that this can be esily shown by a change of basis which represents a rotation)

$$A_{\theta}=\begin{bmatrix} \cos(2\theta)&\sin (2\theta)\\\sin (2\theta)&-\cos(2\theta)\end{bmatrix}$$

and also in this case, by definition, the transformation has eigenvalues $\pm 1$ with eigenvectors $u_1$, $u_2$, it is easy to check indeed that

- $A_{\theta}u_1=u_1$
- $A_{\theta}u_2=-u_2$

[image]

The same argument can be used for any other orthogonal transformation, they can be obtained by rotation starting from a simple transformation with eigenvalues $\pm 1$ which are preseved.